# Windows 8.1 wont boot after installing ubuntu 14.04 (2 drives separate drives)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I have windows 8.1 64bit on my ssd and I installed ubuntu 14.04 64bit on a second hard drive. The PC boots the drive that is first in boot order. Thats the only way to choose OS. What can i do to make my life easier?

CPU: amd fx8320
m/b: Asus M5A97 R2.0

Comment: See Boot Repair, &/or http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? Do you want to change the item in the boot menu that is selected by default?

Comment: The pc booted automatically the OS that was on the first boot device. If i changed the boot order then it boot to the other OS. See my answer below. I used easyBCD and figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

I installed easyBCD, added a new entry for linux and option for ubuntu appeared!
ps: easyBCD is free for individuals